# Video Recording Android by means CameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax, video-recording

I want to record a video using CameraX in Android 8 without showing a surface.

```
private fun Recording()
{val selector = QualitySelector
        .from(
            Quality.UHD,
            FallbackStrategy.higherQualityOrLowerThan(Quality.SD)
        )
    // build a recorder, which can:
    //   - record video/audio to MediaStore(only shown here), File, ParcelFileDescriptor
    //   - be used create recording(s) (the recording performs recording)
    val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
        .setQualitySelector(selector)
        .build()
    videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)
    val name = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)?.absolutePath + "/recording.mp4"
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
    }
    Log.i("WEE",contentValues.toString())
    val mediaStoreOutput = MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(
        contentResolver,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        .setContentValues(contentValues)
        .build()

    // configure Recorder and Start recording to the mediaStoreOutput.
    currentRecording = videoCapture.output.prepareRecording(applicationContext,mediaStoreOutput).withAudioEnabled().start(mainThreadExecutor, captureListener)
    Log.i("TAG", "Recording started")
    sleep(4000)
    currentRecording!!.stop()
    currentRecording = null
}
private val captureListener = Consumer<VideoRecordEvent> { event ->
    // cache the recording state
    Log.i("TAG",event.toString())
    if(event is VideoRecordEvent.Start){
}
```

But it does not work. I get this:

```
2022-08-23 14:46:53.838 3348-3348/com.example.simplecamerax D/Recorder: Transitioning Recorder internal state: INITIALIZING --> PENDING_RECORDING
2022-08-23 14:46:53.838 3348-3348/com.example.simplecamerax I/TAG: Recording started
2022-08-23 14:46:57.838 3348-3348/com.example.simplecamerax D/Recorder: Transitioning Recorder internal state: PENDING_RECORDING --> INITIALIZING
```

I don't understand why it happens and how i can resolve it.